# Activation link to allow committing to database in Django

Tags: database, django, view, activation

So I have an app that takes a form, and sends and e-mail address to somebody, but I want a way to stick and activation URL generated by Django into that e-mail, and not have the form data commit to the database until that activation link is clicked. Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the comments on my first answer, here's a reworked one more suited to your needs.

Create a model, e.g. ServiceHours, that next to the data you want to collect (hours done, supervisor_email, ...), has the following fields:

```
activation_key=models.CharField(_('activation key'), max_length=40, null=True, blank=True)
validated=models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

I'd suggest adding a [post_save signal](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/signals/#django.db.models.signals.post_save) to the Model, so that whenever a new ServiceHours instance is created (by saving the form), the email to the supervisor is sent.

```
# Add this to your models file
# Required imports 

from django.db.models.signals import post_save
from django.utils.hashcompat import sha_constructor
import random

def _create_and_send_activation_key(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    if created:    # Only do this for newly created instances.
        salt = sha_constructor(str(random.random())).hexdigest()[:5]        
        # Set activation key based on supervisor email 
        instance.activation_key = sha_constructor(salt+instance.supervisor_email).hexdigest()
        instance.save()
        # Create email
        subject = "Please validate"
        # In the message, you can use the data the volunteer has entered by accessing 
        # the instance properties
        message = "Include instance hours, volunteer's name etc\n"
        # Insert the activation key & link
        messsage += "Click here: %s" % (reverse("validate_hours", kwargs={'id': instance.id, 'activation_key':instance.activation_key})

        # Send the mail
        from django.core.mail import send_mail # Move this import to top of your file ofcourse, I've just put it here to show what module you need
        send_mail(subject, message, sender, recipients)

post_save.connect(_create_and_send_activation_key, sender=ServiceHours)
```

Define a view to validate service hours based on an activation key

```
  # in views.py
  def validate_hours(request, id, activation_key):
      # find the corresponding ServiceHours instance
      service_hours = ServiceHours.objects.get(id=id, activation_key=activation_key)
      service_hours.validated = True
      service_hours.save()
```

In your urls.py, define an url to your validate_hours view:

```
urlpatterns += patterns('',
    url(r'^validate-hours/(?P<id>[0-9]+)/(?P<activation_key>\w+)', validate_hours, name='validate_hours'),
```

This has all been off the top of my head, so please excuse any errors. I hope you get the gist of the process and can extend according to your exact needs.

Comment: FYI: I've taken parts of the code of django-registration for the creation of the activation_key, credit where credit's due :)

Comment: Everything seems like it should work, thanks :) The only problem is that django.utils.hashcompat has been deprecated in Django 1.6. Any other libraries or solutions that might work without changing much in your answer?

Comment: Apparently [hashlib](http://docs.python.org/2/library/hashlib.html) is now the standard. You might change the line where the activation_key is generated by something like `activation_key = hashlib.sha224(salt+instance.supervisor_email).hexdigest()`. Mind you, this is untested and you might want to increase max_length of the model's validation_key field.

Comment: When I try and click the activation link, the page gives me a TypeError stating validate_hours() got an unexpected keyword argument 'activation_key'. Any ideas as to why? Should I maybe add the _validation\_key_ and _validated_ fields to my ModelForm also?

Comment: Oh right, your view should get `activation_key` and `id`as its arguments -> `def validate_hours(request, id, activation_key)`. You can replace the request.GET.get('id') further in the code with the id variable (same goes for activation_key).

Comment: So `id=request.GET.get('id')` would become `id=id`? Also, should the `validation_key` model be renamed `activation_key`?

Comment: Yes, I've changed the answer accordingly. Check the [answer revision history](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/21133472/revisions) to see what exactly was changed.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to set/unset the `is_active` flag on the user.

Conceptually:

- When a user registers succesfully, be sure to set the flag to False;
- Autogenerate a unique string that is tied to the user's ID and send the activation url via email;
- In the activation view, decompose the key into the user ID and set the is_active flag to True;
- In your login view, check whether the user trying to log in has is_active is True.

Then you'll be sure that users who are logged in have a confirmed email address.

The page in Django's documentation [on user authentication](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/topics/auth/default/) provides all necessary information. For a sample login view, the chapter ["How to log a user in"](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/topics/auth/default/#how-to-log-a-user-in) has one.

If you'd prefer to use a reusable app, [django-registration](https://django-registration.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) might fit your needs perfectly.

(Post-reply addition:) why not commit the data to the database? The "waste" of having unactivated users residing in your database does not outweigh the effort you'd need to implement a solution that does not commit the data to the database. Moreover, it might be more than interesting to have an idea of the amount of unactivated users (and act accordingly).

Comment: I tried to find a way to take said scenario and transfer it to my needs, but the thing is, this isn't for registering new users. I've got that down pat, it's just that I want to use a referral system of sorts for the number of hours of community service someone has done, where the user inputs the name and e-mail address of the supervisor and the number of hours they have completed into the form, and sends and e-mail to the supervisor asking to click on the activation link to confirm the user has done those hours, thus committing them to the database.

Comment: I'd still commit the volunteers' data to the database, and add a flag to the model for the validation by the supervisor (default=False and set to True when validated). It makes following up and retracing history so much easier. But are you looking for ways to send the mail, create a (unique) validation link or is it the database set-up that you're struggling with?

Comment: Thanks. Could you explain in more detail? And it's not the database setup, it's both former options, _especially_ the creation of a unique validation link. Also, I've tried using django-generic-confirmation, but it's outdated and doesn't work with Django 1.6.